# Issue while printing JSON response in label

Tags: swift, api, alamofire

I am new to swift and I am calling API with alamofire method. I am getting response successfully but not able to understand how to parse on label here is my code which I tried

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get).responseJSON
{
    response in
    let result = response.result.value
    print(response)
    if result != nil{
        let data = result as! [String : AnyObject]


        let userdata = data["data"] as! NSDictionary

        let address = userdata["address"]
        let city = userdata["city"]
        let pincode = userdata["pincode"]
        let state = userdata["state"]
        self.lblAddress.text = city as? String
        self.lblCity.text = address as? String
        self.lblpincode.text = pincode as? String
        self.lblstate.text = state as? String
    }
}
```

and here is my response which I am getting

```
SUCCESS: {
    "city_address" = 
    (
        {
            address = "404 palladium business hub.";
            city = Ahmedabad;
            pincode = 380061;
            state = Gujarat;
        }
    );
}
```

Not able to understand where I am going wrong please help me to solve this problem.

output for `print(result)`

```
{
    "city_address" =     (
                {
            address = "404 palladium business hub.";
            city = Ahmedabad;
            pincode = 380061;
            state = Gujarat;
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Use Codable to map json response to your model.

Comment: You have a crash, no, give the error message?  I don't see the key "city_address" in your code. The value is an Array btw.  guard let addresses = data as? [String: Any], let address = addresses.first as? [String: Any]` and then instead of using `userdata`, use `address`. But in a general way, avoid using force unwrap, NSStuff (like NSDictionary), and always update UI in main thread. Finally, Codable in Swift 4 is recommanded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues:

1. The object which contains the address information is the value for key `city_address`
2. This object is clearly an **array** (note the parentheses)

And don't use `NSDictionary` in Swift and the unspecified JSON value is always `Any`.

```
if let result = response.result.value as? [String:Any], 
   let dataArray = result["city_address"] as? [[String : Any]], // maybe even `[[String:String]]`
   let userData = dataArray.first {
      let address = userData["address"]
      let city = userData["city"]
      let pincode = userData["pincode"]
      let state = userData["state"]
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
         self.lblAddress.text = address as? String
...
```

Comment: its still giving me error at if let dataArray = result?["city_address"] here for ? this sign

Comment: Then try to remove the `?` Your code `result != nil` implies that `result` is optional.

Comment: then still giving error and suggestion is coming to add ! or ? but in both giving crash

Comment: My code cannot crash. Please `print(result)` (rather than `response`) and add the output to your question

Comment: According to  `result` output my code is correct (without the `?` after result) and must not crash.

Comment: see without ? i am getting this type of error Value of optional type 'Any?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'subscript' of wrapped base type 'Any'

Comment: and with ? i am getting this type of error Type 'Any' has no subscript members

Comment: yes thanks now this is working properly thanks for helping